# how to fix nltk stanford import error in python

Tags: nltk

I am trying to import stanford ner but getting error:

> NLTK was unable to find the
>   C:/Users/.../stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/all.7class.distsim.crf.ser
>   file! Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the
>   STANFORD_MODELS environment variable.

Below the  code:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
import os
java_path = "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_201/bin/java.exe"

os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = "JAVA_PATH" #this java path you get from command 'echo %PATH%'in terminal 

st = StanfordNERTagger('C:/Users/.../stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/all.7class.distsim.crf.ser',
               'C:/Users/.../stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner.jar',encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Are you sure `stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/all.7class.distsim.crf.ser` this path is correct?  For me `classifiers` folder was not there for previous version.

Comment: C:/Users/Nandhu/Desktop/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/all.7class.distsim.crf.ser",
               "C:/Users/Nandhu/Downloads/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner.jar

Comment: this is the path in new version